# Making an array equal by decreasing elements adjacent to each other

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11

I was doing this exercise in my computer science class for a warm up earlier, which was to find the minimum number of moves to make all the elements in an array equal to each other, where the only operation is to subtract one from an element in an array.

This made me curious about extensions to the problem; for example I immediately thought of an extension, how many moves will it take to make all the elements in an array equal to each other, where the only operation is to subtract one from two elements that are adjacent to each other.

For example:
Given array [4, 6, 4], we can decrease elements in index 0 and 1 to get [3, 5, 4], then [3, 4, 3], then [2, 3, 3], and then decrease elements in index 1 and 2 to get [2, 2, 2]. This would take 4 moves. However, how would we extend this kind of thinking to larger arrays, where we cannot trace this out by hand like I just did above?

Comment: If we restrict the elements of the array to the non-negative integers, then there's a very simple O(nm) algorithm, where `n` is the number of elements in the array, and `m` is the minimum value in the array. All that's needed is to try each possible target value from `m` down to 0, and perform an O(n) check to see if it's possible to reduce all elements of the array to that target.

Comment: It seems that there will not be a solution in many cases. For example, consider `[3 2 3]`.

Comment: At least, all cases where an array has an even number of elements but the sum of all elements is initially odd, don't have a solution. That's because every move subtracts 2 from the sum, so the sum remains odd; but any solution would have to have an even sum, computed as some fixed value times the number of elements (which is even).

Comment: Also all cases where the very first or the very last number is greater than its only neighbor. Any move would either preserve or increase the difference, there's no way to reduce it.

Comment: In summary, if the target value is known, the answer can be computed in O(n) time with O(1) extra space. For an odd length array, a single pass through the array reduces the last element to the target, and a second pass computes the answer. For an even length array, the minimum of the first and last elements *is* the target, and a single pass through the array computes the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether this is possible (and minimum number of moves) in `O(n)` time, in a way that should generalize to larger array decreases.

The first step is to convert our array `A` to the first-difference array `D`, whose elements are `D = [A[1]-A[0], A[2]-A[1], ..., A[n-1]-A[n-2]]`. We are done when `D` is the all-zero array. Now, think about how the operations on `A` translate to changes in `D`. It's different when `n` is even and odd, too, so focus on one case at a time.

---

**Odd length**

When `A` has odd length, there are more cases where no solution is possible.
Suppose 'A' has 7 elements. There's 6 possible moves, so let's calculate what effect each has on `D`.

```
A = [a_0,    a_1,    a_2,    a_3,    a_4,    a_5,    a_6]
D =     [d_0,    d_1,    d_2,    d_3,    d_4,    d_5]

Moves available:
d_1 += 1
(d_0 -= 1, d_2 += 1)
(d_1 -= 1, d_3 += 1)
(d_2 -= 1, d_4 += 1)
(d_3 -= 1, d_5 += 1)
d_4 -= 1
```

Some observations:

1. The interactions between even and odd indices of `D` are completely disjoint (this is true for the even-length case too).
2. `d_5` can only increase, `d_0` can only decrease.

I found it helpful to think of this as a '**flow**' from left to right in `D`:

```
d_0 --> d_2 --> d_4 --> SINK

SOURCE --> d_1 --> d_3 --> d_5
```

this makes things easier: there's only one way to try to make `D` all zero, so we can just try that.

1. If `D[0]` is negative, this is impossible. If it's positive, add `D[0]` moves to our counter, and add `D[0]` to `D[2]`
2. If `D[2]` is negative, this is impossible. If it's positive, add `D[2]` moves to our counter, and add `D[2]` to `D[4]`
3. If `D[4]` is negative, this is impossible. Otherwise, add `D[4]` to our counter. `D[4]` points to a sink, so we are done.

I haven't explained the process for the odd vertices, but it's the same logic-- there's at most one way to make `D` all zero, following the flow.

---

**Even-length**

The even-length array case is similar, except the flow-network has different endpoints.

```
A = [a_0,    a_1,    a_2,    a_3,    a_4,    a_5,    a_6,    a_7]
D =     [d_0,    d_1,    d_2,    d_3,    d_4,    d_5,    d_6]

Moves available:
d_1 += 1
(d_0 -= 1, d_2 += 1)
(d_1 -= 1, d_3 += 1)
(d_2 -= 1, d_4 += 1)
(d_3 -= 1, d_5 += 1)
(d_4 -= 1, d_6 += 1)
d_5 -= 1


d_0 --> d_2 --> d_4 --> d_6

SOURCE --> d_1 --> d_3 --> d_5 --> SINK
```

This means that the odd-indices can have any values without changing the solvability, while the even indices must become all zero with only positive transfers from left to right. Positive flow still moves in exactly one direction in both cases.

I've written a Python solution implementing the logic above. There's one caveat-- I haven't been able to rigorously test it against random input. There's no obviously correct brute-force solution to this problem, so there may be failing testcases that I missed.

```py
def min_decreases_to_get_equal(nums: List[int]) -> Optional[int]:
    """Given an array of integers, returns the number of moves
    to make all elements equal, or None if impossible.
    A move is selecting two adjacent elements and dec. both by 1."""

    n = len(nums)
    assert n >= 2
    if n == 2:
        return 0 if nums[0] == nums[1] else None
    differences = [nums[i] - nums[i - 1] for i in range(1, n)]
    evens = differences[0::2]
    odds = differences[1::2]

    if n % 2 == 0:  # Even length case

        total_cost = 0
        m1 = len(evens)
        for i, x in enumerate(evens):
            if x < 0:
                return None
            elif x > 0:
                # Last element can't be decreased
                if i == m1 - 1:
                    return None

                total_cost += abs(x)
                evens[i + 1] += abs(x)

        m2 = len(odds)
        for i, x in enumerate(odds):
            if x < 0:
                total_cost += abs(x) * (i + 1)
            elif x > 0:
                total_cost += abs(x)
                if i < m2 - 1:
                    odds[i + 1] += x
        return total_cost

    else:  # Odd length case
        total_cost = 0
        m1 = len(evens)
        for i, x in enumerate(evens):
            if x < 0:
                return None
            elif x > 0:
                if i < m1 - 1:
                    evens[i + 1] += abs(x)
                total_cost += abs(x)

        m2 = len(odds)
        for i in reversed(range(m2)):
            x = odds[i]
            if x < 0:
                if i != 0:
                    odds[i - 1] -= abs(x)
                total_cost += abs(x)

            elif x > 0:
                return None

        return total_cost
```

Example tests:

```
[4, 6, 4] --> 4,
[3, 2, 3] --> None,
[0, 8, 8, 14, 8] --> 34,
[2, 5, 1, 6, 12, 11, 7, 0, 1, 1] --> 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the problem that we want to find out what is the smallest number of operations. If we know what is the largest number that equalizes all arrays? We can subtract that number from each other in the array to get the answer. Naively, you can solve this problem by searching for the smallest number in the array and loop checking from `0` to `min(a[i])` then find the minimum operations.

My code in C++

```cpp
// print -1 if not possible to equalize array
void solve() {
    int N; 
    scanf("%d", &N);

    vector<int> a(N);
    int minimum=INT_MAX;
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        minimum=min(minimum, a[i]);
    }

    if(N==1) {  // Initially check when N=1 or N=2
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }
    else if(N==2) {
        printf("%d\n", (a[0]==a[1] ? 0 : -1));
        return;
    }

    vector<int> temp=a;  // temporary array for storing array before operation
    for(int target=minimum; target>=0; --target) {
        a=temp;
        bool check=true;  // check array equal?
        int operation=0;  // count number operations
        for(int j=0; j<N-1; ++j) {
            int subtract=a[j]-target;
            operation+=2*subtract;
            a[j]-=subtract;
            a[j+1]-=subtract;
            if(a[j]<target || a[j+1]<target) {  // all element should equal to target
                check=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(check==true) {
            printf("%d\n", operation);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("-1\n");  // not possible
}
```

But the above method will be slow when N is large.

For this problem, the [Greedy Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) can be used to solve it. Now let's look at the situations when this array can't be equalized. If you want to make an array with `a[i-1] != a[i]` to be equal, what do you have to do? Assume we're iterating over an array and come into the following cases.

First, if `a[i-1] > a[i]` , then we have to perform operation at the left-hand in order to equal make it to the right-hand side, that is, `a[i-2]` and `a[i-1]` must be executed. For example **8 8 7** to **7 7 7**.
Please note that if `i` equals `1`, it needs the initial element of an array. It will be unable to operate.

Second, if `a[i-1] < a[i]` , then we have to perform operation at the right-hand in order to make it equal to the left-hand side, that is, `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` must be executed. For example **5 6 6** to **5 5 5**.
Please note that if `i` equals `N-1`, it is the last element of an array. It will be unable to operate. Naturally, the prior ones have been equalized.

After that, we can use Greedy to keep the array equal. We'll traverse over the array one by one, checking for the conditions listed above. If it can do it, it ought to. Continue until you are unable to do so or discover that this array is stuck at the very first or final position. This one will be quicker than the previous one.

Here is my code.

```cpp
// print -1 if not possible to equalize array
void solve() {
    int N; 
    scanf("%d", &N);

    vector<int> a(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    if(N==1) {
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }
    else if(N==2) {
        printf("%d\n", (a[0]==a[1] ? 0 : -1));
        return;
    }

    if(a[N-2]<a[N-1] || a[0]>a[1]) { 
        printf("-1\n");
        return;
    }

    long long operation=0;
    bool check=true;  // check if the array has changed
    while(check) {
        check=false;
        for(int i=1; i<N; ++i) {
            if(a[i-1]<a[i]) {
                if(i==N-1) {
                    printf("-1\n");
                    return;
                }
                check=true;
                int subtract=a[i]-a[i-1];
                operation+=2*subtract;
                a[i]-=subtract;
                a[i+1]-=subtract;
                if(a[i]<0 || a[i+1]<0) {
                    printf("-1\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if(a[i-1]>a[i]) {
                if(i==1) {
                    printf("-1\n");
                    return;
                }
                check=true;
                int subtract=a[i-1]-a[i];
                operation+=2*subtract;
                a[i-2]-=subtract;
                a[i-1]-=subtract;
                if(a[i-2]<0 || a[i-1]<0) {
                    printf("-1\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n", (a[N-1]>=0 ? operation : -1));  // array already equal but may less than zero
}
```

This may be accomplished in a variety of ways, and there is a better approach than the one I've presented. However, I believe that this is sufficient to go through test cases 1 <= `N` <= 10<sup>5</sup> and 0 <= `a[i]` <= 10<sup>9</sup>.